# Import CSV file in Mysql using PHP but only 214 rows out of 236 rows are imported

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have to import a CSV file of 236 rows. But only 144/213 rows are imported.
My server only support mysql command. it doesn't support mysqli.

enter code here

```
fgetcsv($file);
fgetcsv($file);
while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
$sql = "INSERT into branchiss2 (date,bank_id,branch_id,coa_id,coa_des,amount,is_conv,off_ind,bl1,bl2,fig_ind,data_cat,field_des,bl3,bl4,bl5,bl6,bl7,bl8,bl9) 
values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[0])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[2])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[3])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[4])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[5])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[6])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[7])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[8])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[9])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[10])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[11])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[12])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[13])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[14])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[15])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[16])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[17])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[18])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($getData[19])."')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
     }
fclose($file);  

     }
```

Comment: show full code of csv file

Comment: I edited my questions and code. Please see it.

Comment: check the line where it breaks, it could be that CSV file has data quality issue - a missing or an extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

It may be stopped because of memory issue please add this 2 line beginning of code hope it will help you or use phpexcel library.

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :
MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE statement for reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed

for example :-

```
$import_query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$fileName'
     INTO TABLE tableName
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (column1,column2,column3)
     SET column4 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
eof;

$db->query($import_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modified your php.ini file set **max_execution_time** to a time you think is apropiated.